# Creating 'News' section with cmsplugin_blog Django CMS application

Tags: django-cms

How do I create a generic 'News' section, that would use cmsplugin_blog and be displayed on all pages. Is it possible to tell Django CMS in base.html to include the app on all pages? The content of each news entry should be displayed in the main block of the page.

My base.html looks something like this:

```
    ...
    {% block base_content %}
    {% endblock %}
    ...

    {% block right-column %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Each page that should have a news short list in the right column with links to individual news entries that should be displayed in the base content block when clicked on the link.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this would be to create a page which is published but not in the navigation and add an instance of the blog plugin to that page and then in your "master" template you can display the contents of that placeholder (which will be the blog plugin instance) using the following template tag:

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#show-placeholder